# Do I need to use Membership services with NTLM

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ntlm

If I have an ASP.Net MVC applicaiton where users can only access via an NTLM authenticate account, do I need to use ASP.Net Membership services and issue cookies?

Or do I have completely the wrong end of this particular stick?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You never have to use the asp.net membership provider, it is just an option. If all you need to do is authenticating the user, NTML works just fine by itself. If you need to use the user's identity for further authorization or personalization on the site you need to use some sort of user management, but it doesn't have to be the membership provider, you can write your own or your own.
I doesn't make any difference whether you are using mvc or web-forms.